# Optionally display a widget on tablet devices

Tags: android, widget, tablet

I have an application that has a set of widgets. I would like to create another widget that should only be visible/selectable by the user if the device it is running on is a tablet.

I have tried to do this by setting the enabled attribute of the tablet-only receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `="@bool/isTablet"`, ie, `android:enabled="@bool/isTablet"` and define the isTablet boolean in a `bools.xml` file which is placed in the

```
/res/values 
/res/values-sw600dp 
/res/values-sw720dp folders
```

The isTablet boolean is set to `false` (for `/res/values`) and `true` in the `/res/values-sw600dp` and `/res/values-sw720dp` folders.

This does not work though - the widget is never visible; if I set the enabled attribute of the receiver to true, the widget becomes visible, so the issue looks like the related boolean value (isTablet) is not read properly in the Android manifest.

Is this possible to do and if so, how?

Comment: What does `Context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)` return when run on a tablet ?

Comment: It returns true for a tablet, as it us defined in the corresponding bools.xml file.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the problem might be coming from using `@bool/isTablet`. I'm not sure this enables multiple versions. Did you try changing it to `?bool/isTablet` ?